# How can I insert images into a Redactor rich text field in a front-end form?

Tags: redactor, image, upload, frontend-form

I want to allow registered users to insert (i.e. upload) images into a Redactor rich text field in a front-end form.

I dowloaded the Image Manager plugin from Imperavi (https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/imagemanager/) and set up my Redactor config as follows:

```
{% includeJsResource "lib/redactor/redactor.js" %}
{% includeJsResource "lib/redactor/plugins/source.js" %}
{% includeJsResource "lib/redactor/plugins/fullscreen.js" %}
{% includeJsResource "lib/redactor/plugins/imagemanager.js" %}
{% includeCssResource "lib/redactor/redactor.css" %}

{% set redactorJS %}
    $('#{{ elId }}').redactor({
        buttons: ['format', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', 'lists', 'link', 'html', 'image'],
        formatting: ['p', 'blockquote', 'h2', 'h3'],
        plugins: ['source','fullscreen', 'imagemanager'],
        minHeight: 300,
        imageUpload: '/upload.php',
    });
{% endset %}
{% includeJs redactorJS %}
```

I can see the image button in the toolbar and the browse files modal when I click the image button. However, it doesn’t upload anything because `imageUpload: '/upload.php',` is obviously incorrect. What, if anything, can I replace `upload.php` with? If this isn’t possible, what else could I do to achieve this functionality? Thanks!

**UPDATE**:

I have the following code in `craft/plugins/imagesuploaderscript/controllers/ImagesUploaderScriptController.php` from CloudApp share link in comment below:

```
namespace Craft;
```

class ImagesUploaderScriptController extends BaseController
{

```
protected $valid_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
protected $assetSourceId = 1;
protected $assetFolderId = 1;

public function actionUpload()
{
    $this->requireAjaxRequest();

    $errors = array();
    $success = array();

    if (!$_FILES['file']['error'])
    {
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (!in_array($extension, $this->valid_extensions))
        {
            $errors[] = "$filename has an invalid extension.";
        } else {
            $uploadDir = craft()->assetSources->getSourceById($this->assetSourceId)->settings['path'];

            if (move_uploaded_file($file, $uploadDir . $filename))
            {
                IOHelper::deleteFile($file);

                $file = $uploadDir . $filename;

                $fileModel = new AssetFileModel();
                $fileModel->sourceId = $this->assetSourceId;
                $fileModel->folderId = $this->assetFolderId;
                $fileModel->filename = IOHelper::getFileName($filename);
                $fileModel->kind = IOHelper::getFileKind(IOHelper::getExtension($filename));
                $fileModel->size = filesize($file);
                $fileModel->dateModified = IOHelper::getLastTimeModified($file);

                craft()->assets->storeFile($fileModel);

                // print_r($fileModel);

                // displaying file
                $image = array(
                    'url' => 'images/'.$filename,
                    'id' => 1
                );
                $this->returnJSON($image);
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $errors[] = "$filename was unable to be saved.";
            }
        }
    }

    $this->returnJSON(compact('errors'));
    exit;
}
```

}

How do I get my form to talk to it? Also, what else do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a really quick and dirty solution without messing things up in some way or another. The best way would be creating a custom redactor plugin. Craft made it's own for that `craft/app/resources/js/craft/redactor.js::10511` you could search for an existing one or create your own. All in all you have to send a request to the AssetController with the file and the parent folder and return the img tag. I've done it with https://quilljs.com but not with the redactor. If you want I can show you the default code

Comment: Hi Robin, Thanks! Quill looks quite nice. I would be very interested in seeing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seems possible natively, you should write a custom upload script.

→ [Example #1](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/upload-images/)

→ [Example #2](https://gist.github.com/sathoro/8178981#file-controller-php)

If it doesn't matter to add the images inside your rich text field, one more simple workaround could be to allow image upload to your assets using a separate upload field.

→ [Uploading Files from Front-end Entry Forms](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#uploading-files-from-front-end-entry-forms)

Comment: Hi Romain, Thanks. The front-end form is to publish blog posts. I already have a separate upload field for the posts' featured image. However, I want users to be able to insert images between paragraphs. Ideally, I'd do this with a Matrix field, but my JS skills are insufficient to add new blocks on the front-end. I saw example #1. However, example #2 looks more interesting since I would also like to rename files on upload. I would basically be creating a plugin, correct? Could I use pluginfactory.io and select Controllers comp. & put content of ex. #2 in it?

Comment: Yes, you should write a plugin with a controller. Content of example #2 is a good start, but it needs some adaptations to works with Redactor. I made a first draft, which starts to work ; I could send it to you later.

Comment: Hi Romain, that would be most helpful. I don't have any experience with plugin development yet, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm still very busy since my previous message.

Here is perhaps something to start: https://cl.ly/2p0C3q1g2q0p. Please note that this will not work as it is currently, it's just a quick first draft.

Hope you can start something with this. I don't have so experience in plugin development, but don't be afraid, your request is a very good opportunity to learn!

Comment: Many thanks, Romain, I'll give it a go and when I get it working, I'll share it with Craft community.